# Is there a way to take multiple outfiles from a single select query in mysql based on a data value in where condition?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a file that contains a particular column values of a table eg. file.txt has 
1
2
3
... 
and in a shell script, i loop the select statement with this values lik
file=$1
for line in `cat $file`
do
select * into outfile '/path/filename.txt' where colvalue='$line';
Now, I want a way in which for each value ie, 1,2,3 the output to be written into the same file. In ideal case, it throws an error as" file already exists"..

Comment: you can do it with linux. please show me a sample from the txt file

Comment: its jus an id value
file.txt
56879
656586
87879 each with a line break (not in a single line)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
Sort and uniq removes duplicate entrys
sed will annd , and quote the args
tr -d will remove the newlines (only for optic)

**my input file**

```
$ cat n.txt
1
3
5
66
99
2
```

**generate a query**

```
$ echo "select * into outfile '/path/filename.txt' where colvalue in (" > query.sql
$ sort n.txt | uniq |sed -e "s/^\(.*\)$/'\1'/" -e '2,$s/^/,/g' | tr -d '\n' >> query.sql
$ echo ");" >> query.sql
```

**show the query (only to verify)**

```
$ cat query.sql
select * into outfile '/path/filename.txt' where colvalue in (
'1','2','3','5','66','99');
```

**run the query**

```
$ mysql -u root < query.sql
```